# Comparing two String hours in Java Errorr

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, java-time

I have an Error cause my app stops while I do the comparison between 2 String hours (time, time2), the first one its takes from the result of my time picker and the other one its the time on mi smartphone

### Failed ways that I tried to compare bought Strings:

First way:

```
          if(time.equals(time2))
          {

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SAME VALUE: "+time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          else
          {

          }
```

Second way:

```
          if(time == time2)
          {

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SAME VALUE: "+time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          else
          {

          }
```

---

Here its all the code

```
                 @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {

                    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timetext);
                    textView.setText("Hour: " + hour + "   Minutes:" + minute );

                    String Shour = Integer.toString(hour);
                    String Sminute = Integer.toString(minute);
                    final String time2 = Shour + ":" +Sminute;
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

                    final String time = format.format(calendar.getTime());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "vlaue is "+time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Timer t = new Timer();
                    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(time.equals(time2)){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SAME VALUE: "+time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            else{

                            }
                        }
                    },0,1000);
                }
```

Comment: please post the error

Comment: While I build the app on android studio everything works fine, but when I run the app and make the comparison at my Android Emulator or my Smart Phone the app Stops, so I can't tell you the specific error :/

Comment: Firstly, never use "==" when comparing Strings;  From your code above, that will ALWAYS return false.  Secondly, again for your code above, your `time.equals(time2)` could equally well (or rather : better ) be performed outside the timer - have you tried that?   Offhand, I can't see a reason for a failure in the code, though.

Comment: Thirdly ;) : when generating `time2`, you are not adding leading-zeros for in case of single-digit hours/minutes.    A `time2` value of "9:5" is not the same string value as the "09:05" you'd get for `time`.

Comment: If your app stops you can get from the `Logcat` the error stack trace. Post it, please.

Comment: Thanks for help racrama ;), I'm going to try again what you say, cause I still have the same Error

Comment: Here its the result Error in Logcat Luca, cause I'm new and I don't know how to edit my post :)

Comment: 04-22 23:20:54.398 5509-5653/com.example.pc.AppE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
            java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
            at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:306)
            at com.example.pc.proyectofinal.AccountActivity.Atwo$6.run(Atwo.java:179)
            at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
            04-22 23:20:54.508 5509-5509/com.example.pc.proyectofinal E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Comment: By the way, you are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* with the adoption of JSR 310.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining what @racraman mentioned in the comments about timer2 and the answer above. Here is an answer

```
     ...
     // format the string of timer2 to add a zero when it is a single digit so that it matches with the date format you have used ie HH:mm
      @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {

                TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timetext);
                textView.setText("Hour: " + hour + "   Minutes:" + minute );

                // String Shour = Integer.toString(hour);
                // String Sminute = Integer.toString(minute);
                final String time2 = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d:%02d", hour, minute);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

                final String time = format.format(calendar.getTime());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "vlaue is "+time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Timer t = new Timer();
                t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(time.equals(time2)){
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SAME VALUE: "+time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                              public void run() {
                                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SAME VALUE: "+time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                              }
                            }
                        }
                        else{

                        }
                    }
                },0,1000);
            }
```

in addition, as you progress, learn to make good use of Logcat with various logging methods and also the Debugging tools by adding breakpoints ( they are more effective at finding bugs in your app)

Comment: Thanks N. Hubert and everybody for the help! The problem was solved with the N. Hubert code! :)

Comment: @FLUP glad to hear that. You can then select this answer as the right one.